# How to develop a new feature branch meanwhile others change Main branch with git?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-branch, pull-request

we have a project which many developers working on it .
every time I want to develop a feature
1- pull latest changes from remote repo to my local and
2- I create a branch locally and do my changes on it and
3- push the newly created branch to remote repo
4- create a pull request to say some changes to somebody come and review it

and reviewer say to me : you have to make some changes to your branch because you have to consider some guidelines

so I go back to my local rep . meanwhile of developing this feature other developers of team push some changes to Main branch on remote repo

now should I pull them first to my Main branch of local repo to have latest changes and merge Main branch to my local feature branch before working on it or not ?

how is the flow in this situation ?

Comment: After completing the changes in local, you need to pull the changes(called merging/rebasing) from the `main` branch. If there are any merge conflicts, resolve them and then push it to remote.

Answer (score 2):

Once your review or comments are been provided. Come back to your local and make a `git pull`. Assuming that other developers in the team had made their commits and pushed them to the remote repo.
Once `git pull` is performed you could see the new changes in the local. Then make sure you're on the feature branch you're working on. Then perform `git merge main` or `git rebase main` as per requirement.

[Check this when to use rebase or merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804115/when-do-you-use-git-rebase-instead-of-git-merge)

Once merge or rebase is performed make your new changes *commit* them and *push* them.